# Opencart page stopped unexpectedly with a message "Use of undefined constant VERSION - assumed 'VERSION' "?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant VERSION - assumed 'VERSION' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/xxxxxxx/you-r.in/public_html/catalog/controller/extension/module/so_extra_slider.php on line 193
```

The site has stopped working and suddenly displaying this message warning. Nothing is updated neither the php nor the Opencart version. 
Here is how the code looks:

```
// Check Version
if(version_compare(VERSION, '2.1.0.2', '>')) {
    if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
        $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
    } else {
        $price = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you take it up with the [developer of the Slider](https://codecanyon.net/item/so-extra-slider-responsive-opencart-module/13024810) that is causing the error? Or disable the extension? You could also suppress this warning in your PHP settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `index.php` where normally version is defined. For example

```
<?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '2.3.0.2.3');
```

You may add version definition like this

```
define('VERSION', 'your-version-number');
// Check Version
if(version_compare(VERSION, '2.1.0.2', '>')) {
```